# Help with calculating phase and y-axis offset for sine functions

Tags: trigonometry

I have a function of type $f(x)=\sin(ax+b \pi/2)$ where $a$ and $b$ are known.
I want to copy this function, add a phase shift, then globally raise it.
Lets call it $g(x)= \sin(ax+b \pi/2 + c\pi/2)+d$
where $c$ and $d$ represent the additional phase shift and global raise, respectively.

I want to find $c,d$ that will make $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ intersect at 2 points on the x-axis:

1. whatever $x$ value is at when $f(x)=1$
2. $x = \pi/2$, and this needs to be the minimum $y$ value for $g(x)$ as shown in the example chart ($f(x)$ is red, $g(x)$ is blue)

How can I express $c,d$ using the other known variables? I'm looking for a formula that will work on any arbitrary values of $a,b$.
If I didn't make it clear, both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same sine rate.

[image]

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).